# Get system default web proxy in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, proxy

The following code takes a target uri and gets its content as stream. Before the network call is made, it checks whether a proxy is required to access the target uri or not.

This works perfectly for .NET apps in full-framework (i.e. v4.8):

```
    var targetUri = new Uri("...");
    HttpClient client;

    // get the system default web proxy ...
    var proxyUri = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(targetUri);

    // ... and check whether it should be used or not
    var proxyAuthorityEqualsTargetAuthority = proxyUri?.Authority?.Equals(targetUri.Authority) == true;
    var proxyRequired = !proxyAuthorityEqualsTargetAuthority;

    if (proxyRequired)
    {
        var proxy = new WebProxy()
        {
            Address = proxyUri,
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };

        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = proxy };
        client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
    }
    else
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
    }

    await client.GetStreamAsync(targetUri) ...
```

However it does not work within a .NET Core app:

Accessing `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(targetUri)` will throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`:

> Operation is not supported on this platform.

So I tried this line instead which is supported by .NET Core as well:

```
    // deprecated: var proxyUri = new Uri(WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(targetUri).AbsoluteUri);
    var proxyUri = new WebProxy().GetProxy(targetUri);
```

However, the returning `proxyUri.Authority` does always return the `targetUri` now (both, in .NET and .NET Core) instead of the address to the proxy server like `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(targetUri)` does in .NET.

This way, `proxyAuthorityEqualsTargetAuthority` is always true and therefore, `proxyRequired` is always false. Accessing the target uri directly throws a `407 (Proxy Authentication Required)`.

#### Does anyone know how to get the address of the default web proxy in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know what I missed as I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52701989/704281) weeks ago. I tried again and everything seems fine.

With `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`, this short code works with both: .NET and .NET Core.

```
    var targetUri = new Uri("...");

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var client = new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: true);

    await client.GetStreamAsync(targetUri) ...
```